# Iterate through XML variable in SQL Server whether what is in XML

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

In SQL Server, how can I query the following XML

```
<Employee>
   <FirstName>David</FirstName>
   <LastName>Jons</LastName>
   <Age>28</Age>
</Employee>
<Employee>
   <FirstName>Eric</FirstName>
   <LastName>Terry</LastName>
   <Age>36</Age>
</Employee>
<Employee>
   <FirstName>Kady</FirstName>
   <LastName>Campell</LastName>
   <Age>21</Age>
</Employee>
```

If the element names are the same, we can use the approach below:

[Iterate through XML variable in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499268/iterate-through-xml-variable-in-sql-server)

Therefore, How to get the following result or something like that:

```
FirstName   |  LastName   | Age
----------- +-------------+-----
David       |   Jons      | 28
Eric        |   Terry     | 36
Kady        |   Campell   | 21
```

given that I don't know the element name of the XML such as FisrtName, LastName, Age,

I think I hope to get result like this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
```

in which I don't know the column name of table `Employee`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<Employee>
   <FirstName>David</FirstName>
   <LastName>Jons</LastName>
   <Age>28</Age>
</Employee>
<Employee>
   <FirstName>Eric</FirstName>
   <LastName>Terry</LastName>
   <Age>36</Age>
</Employee>
<Employee>
   <FirstName>Kady</FirstName>
   <LastName>Campell</LastName>
   <Age>21</Age>
</Employee>'

SELECT
    FirstName = xc.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    LastName = xc.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Age = xc.value('(Age)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/Employee') AS XT(XC)
```

That should give you an output of:

```
FirstName   LastName    Age
---------------------------
David       Jons         28
Eric        Terry        36
Kady        Campell      21
```

Comment: Thanks!! but if I don't know there are 3 columns such as FirstName, LastName and age. Can I do something dynamically like SELECT * FROM Employee?